# UIAlertview in 2 view

Tags: xcode, uialertview

I have a alertview that starts in a view A  and must stop in view B. How can I stop the alertview on  B?

thks

Comment: You'll need to describe your scenario a little more...

Answer (score 1):

How are you moving from A to B while a UIAlertView is displayed? Maybe post some code.

This scenario does not seem user-friendly, but there is a way you can dismiss the alert from A in B.

### View A

Create an `NSNotificationCenter` and point it to a method that dismisses the alert:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissAlert) name:@"dismissAlert" object:nil];
```

And the notification should call something like the following:

```
- (void) dismissAlert:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0 animated: YES];
}
```

### View B

Now when you want to dismiss the alert, call the notification you created in **View A**:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"dismissAlert" object:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:`